# VSCode Highlight words by regex on specific file ext

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have some text files with ".qq" extentions. Inside is plain text. I want to color different regex matches in VSCode for this files.

Like all words starting with 0x* should be blue, etc

How can I do this?

Comment: See the Highlight extension.

Comment: Use the [Highlight extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight), as @Mark suggested. You can also create your own extension: [VSCode Docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide)